# Infinite animation using calc is not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I have created a simple loading grid in my application, and added an animation over it. This animation seems to work in every browser except IE11.

Can somebody help me understand why it doesn't work and how to get it working in IE11?

```css
.loading {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 12px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animation {
  animation: loading 1.2s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {left: -30rem}
  to {left: calc(100% + 30rem)}
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle if you're interested: https://jsfiddle.net/9shufwsL/

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809544/css3-animation-is-not-working-in-ie11-but-works-in-other-browsers

Comment: Try this `animation: loading 1.2s infinite;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar not as much, because my problem is not answered by anything in the answer to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `calc()` does not work in this context.

I changed the value of `left` in `keyframes` to use a percent based endpoint and it works in IE11.

```css
.loading {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 12px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animation {
  animation: loading 1.2s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {left: -30rem}
  to {left: 110%}
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rob and so we would think but it does not work in this particular case where `calc()` is within `@keyframes`. A search for IE11 calc bug returns many hits. Go figure...

Comment: After briefly reading a comment elsewhere, I question whether using `calc()` in a keyframe even makes sense but I haven't given it any thought. Seems keyframe should be doing the calculating and `calc()` shouldn't be used at all.

Answer (score 1):

`calc()` does not work in IE you could change the @keyframes to:

```
@keyframes loading {
  from {left: -30rem}
  to {left: 30rem}
}
```

you could use `-moz-calc` and it would work but honestly not the best thing to do.

your keyframes would look like so:

```
@keyframes loading {
  from {left: -30rem}
  to {left: -moz-calc(100% + 30rem)}
}
```

Comment: Thx for the Page-Link Rob, i just tested Jesse's code in IE11 and Edge and both did not work for me. But it did work with the Code of the correct answer and both code snippets of mine answer.